# Java Build Path Entries not found in Deployment Assembly

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, sts

I'm upgrading from STS 3.9.11 to STS 4.18.1.

When I try to run my web project on a STS Tomcat Server (8.5) and receive the infamous `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher` that I received also while developing on STS 3.9. I used to solve that just going to build-path -> deployment assembly and adding the maven dependencies from there. However I just can't find "java build path entries" on this version nor I can add maven dependencies to the deployment assembly. Is there something I am doing wrong?

I already tried the same process that I did on prior versions, updated the project and cleaned the Tomcat server directory.

Comment: Exactly how are you running your project without those preference pages being there?

Comment: @nitind at the time writing I just cannot run the project. But before I added the maven dependencies via deployment assembly. It looks like those maven libs are not being deployed with the project on this new version either. I just can't figure out how to add them as I see no option to do that.